# Show that the solution of this differential equation is analytic

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analyticity

Let $\alpha,\beta,a,b$ be real constants. Show that the differential equation given by:

$y''= ay' + by \\
y(0)=\alpha\\
y'(0)=\beta$

has an unique solution and this solution is analytic in $\mathbb{R}$

Solution:

I am trying to bound $\frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}$ by some $M$, to show it is analytic. I know that if $y$ is an analytic solution of this function, then it must be infinitely differentiable and, hence, must be continuous. Then, for $x$ in $[-R,R]$, $y$ must be bounded by some $M$.

After that, I am trying to show by induction that
$$y^{(n+2)}= (y'')^{n}=(\alpha y' + by)^{n}= \alpha y^{(n+1)} + by^{(n)}.$$

So I need to show that $   y^{(n+1)} $ and $ y^{(n)} $ are bounded (which is what I am trying to show by induction). However, I am having trouble with the first step $n=1$ of the induction. Moreover, I am not using the hypothesis given regarding the behavior of the derivatives in $x=0$.

Thanks!

Comment: I'll bet you meant to write $y'' = ay' + by$ instead of $y'' = \alpha y + by$ as your first equation.  Am I right?  Cheers!

Comment: Yes, I corrected it!

Comment: How so?  Not to be picayune, but that equation still looks like $y'' = \alpha y' + by$ to me!  Did you remember to save your edits? Wassup?

Comment: My first equation is $y''=\alpha y' + by$ and that is how it looks to me ? :s

Comment: He fixed the missing prime, but not the $\alpha$ in place of $a$.

Comment: But I asked if you meant $y'' = ay' + by$!  Do you really want the coefficient of $y'$ to be the same as $y(0)$?  If yes, so be it!

Comment: You are right! I am sorry!

Comment: No need to apologize; the main thing is we got it right, no?  Carry on!

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it.  $y'(x)$ must be continuous because $y''(x)$ exists. As $y'(x)$ is on a bounded interval, then it must be bounded.

So I take $t=max(|a|,|b|)$, and $M=max(M1,M2)$ which are the bounds for the first derivative and the original function.

Finally, $y^{(n+2)}= (y'')^{n}=(\alpha y' + by)^{n}= \alpha y^{(n+1)} + by^{(n)} \leq |a|Mt^{n+1}(n+1)!+|b|Mt^{n}n! \leq Mt^{n}n!(2t^2(n+1)) \leq Mt^{n+2}(n+2)!$

Then in an interval $(-R,R)$ all the derivatives are bounded and the function is analytic.